Remove substring between two characters in SQL Column
Lets say I have  a table T with a column called S



Code
S




1
\String\ String


2
Laser \Laser\


3
La\ser\s and \S\trings



I want to remove every substring in each row of T.S that is between \ and \ and replace it with nothing  such that Table T becomes



Code
S




1
string


2
Laser


3
Las and trings



I have figured out how to identify the characters between the first instance of \ and \
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN -- Checking to ensure temp table does not exist, and dropping anyone that does to avoid errors

    DROP TABLE #t;
END;

GO

--- Create Temp Table to store values and manipulate before inserting into production table ----

CREATE TABLE #t
(
Code VARCHAR(MAX)
,S VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #t (Code ,S )
VALUES ('1','\String\ String'),
        ('2','Laser \Laser\'),
        ('3', 'La\ser\s and \S\trings')
SELECT *
FROM   #t;


SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(s, start_pos,  end_pos - start_pos  
    +1), '\', '\'), '\', '\')

FROM   (SELECT s,
               CHARINDEX('\', s) AS start_pos, 
               CHARINDEX('\', s, CHARINDEX('\', s) + 1) AS end_pos
        FROM   #t) t 

This returns



S




\String\


\Laser\


\ser\



Where I am stuck is on

How do I get it to apply to all instances of \ \ in the same line individually (see line 3)

Apply this change to the column in an update (I'm thinking a cross apply might be useful here)



If this were SQL Server 2022 (or later) we could:

Use STRING_SPLIT(,,1) to break up the string at the \ delimiters and assign each part an ordinal value.
Filter out the even substrings (leaving the odd).
Reassemble the remaining parts using STRING_AGG().
Add a TRIM() to clean up leading or trailing whitespace.

Something like:
SELECT
    T.Code,
    TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal)) AS Answer
FROM #t T
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T.S, '\', 1) SS
WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
GROUP BY T.Code

The third parameter of STRING_SPLIT() generates an ordinal along side each value (available in SQL Server 2022 and later). This is referenced in the WITHIN GROUP(...) clause of the STRING_AGG() function to guarantee the proper ordering or the reassembled components.
If this is part of a more complicated query, you can encapsulate the logic within a CROSS APPLY whose result can then be referenced elsewhere.
SELECT
    T.Code,
    CA.Answer
FROM #t T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal)) AS Answer
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(T.S, '\', 1) SS
    WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
) CA
ORDER BY T.Code

For SQL Server 2019, the STRING_SPLIT() function does not support the enable_ordinal option, so this function cannot be used when we need to guarantee order. An alternative is to use a technique that first maps the string into a JSON array, and then uses OPENJSON() to parse that array.
SELECT
    T.Code,
    CA.Answer
FROM #t T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal)) AS Answer
    FROM (
        SELECT J.value, CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 AS ordinal
        FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(T.S, 'json'), '\\', '","'), '"]')) J
    ) SS
    WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
) CA
ORDER BY T.Code

The above will convert the source string into a JSON array that is then parsed into individual elements by OPENJSON().  The STRING_ESCAPE() function protects the JSON against certain special characters (particularly any embedded double quotes) that would otherwise cause an error. The key value returned by OPENJSON() above is a zero-based string that must be converted to an integer and offset by 1 to match the STRING_SPLIT() ordinal.
NOTE: There are several STRING_SPLIT() alternatives out there, but few yield a reliable ordinal value. (There are actually several bad answers out there that use post-split numbering logic that appears to work, but whose results are not guaranteed by any documented feature, and which may break at any time - especially when scaled up.)
The results are the same for each of the above:



Code
Answer




1
String


2
Laser


3
Las and trings



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
An update in place can be performed with the following:
UPDATE T
SET S = CA.Answer
FROM #t T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal)) AS Answer
    FROM (
        SELECT J.value, CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 AS ordinal
        FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(T.S, 'json'), '\\', '","'), '"]')) J
    ) SS
    WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
) CA

Or if you prefer to include the calculation directly in the select statement:
UPDATE T
SET S = (
    SELECT TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal))
    FROM (
        SELECT J.value, CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 AS ordinal
        FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(T.S, 'json'), '\\', '","'), '"]')) J
    ) SS
    WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
)
FROM #t T

See this updated db<>fiddle.

I am getting an error 'String_Split is an invalid object name'

@ThomasShort - After seeing the SQL Server version tag in the original question, I updated the above answer to include a 2019 version of the code. See the section above starting with "for SQL Server 2019..."

Okay thank you. Im trying to update the table now '''
UPDATE ST
SET S = (SELECT ST2.Code,CA.Answer
FROM #t ST2
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TRIM(STRING_AGG(SS.value, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SS.ordinal)) AS Answer
FROM (
SELECT J.value, CONVERT(int, [key]) + 1 AS ordinal
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(ST2.S, 'json'), '\', '","'), '"]')) J
) SS
WHERE SS.ordinal % 2 != 0 -- Keep the odd parts
) CA
)
FROM dbo.#t ST''' Gets me the error Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Essentially how do I structure this within an update statement so I can use the updated table late in my query. Ive tried using inner joins, using exists and I cant seem to get the syntax right

The answer is simpler than that. Since the SELECT statement posted earlier already accesses the table and has calculates the answer, it is just a simple matter of replacing the SELECT ... clause with UPDATE T SET S = CA.Answer. See my updated answer above.

See example with  recursive query
with r as (
  select 0 lvl, code,s
    ,case when CHARINDEX('\', s)>0 and  CHARINDEX('\', s, CHARINDEX('\', s) + 1)>0 then
        substring(s,1,CHARINDEX('\', s)-1)
       +substring(s,CHARINDEX('\', s, CHARINDEX('\', s) + 1)+1,len(s)) 
     else s
     end rest
  from #t
  union all
  select r.lvl+1,code,s
    ,case when CHARINDEX('\', rest)>0 
            and  CHARINDEX('\',rest, CHARINDEX('\',rest) + 1)>0 then
        substring(rest,1,CHARINDEX('\', rest)-1)
       +substring(rest,CHARINDEX('\', rest, CHARINDEX('\', rest) + 1)+1,len(s)) 
     else rest
     end rest
  from r where CHARINDEX('\', rest)>0 and CHARINDEX('\',rest, CHARINDEX('\',rest) + 1)>0
)
update #t
  set s=rest
from #t t
left join(
    select * ,max(lvl)over(partition by code) rn
    from r
  )src on src.code= t.code  and src.rn=src.lvl

for test data



Code
S
S_upd




1
\String\ String
 String


2
Laser \Laser\
Laser


3
La\ser\s and \S\trings
Las and trings


4
Las\ and String
Las\ and String


5
Las\ and String\
Las


6
Las and String\
Las and String|


7
\Las and String
\Las and String


8
\Las and String\



9
\L\as and String\
as and String\



Demo
